# Unable to display that the maximum characters exceeded

Tags: java, android, input-filter

I am developing an Android application in which I would like to set Input filter to allow only 21 characters in the EditText.

The XML code snippet I have used is follows

```
                             <EditText
                                android:id="@+id/screen_name"
                                android:layout_width="300dp"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:background="#00000000"
                                android:enabled="false"
                                android:gravity="center"
                                android:hint="Enter your screen name"
                                android:maxLength="21"
                                android:text="Raghunathan KE"
                                android:textColor="#fff"
                                android:textSize="24sp"
                                android:textStyle="bold"
                                android:inputType="text"
                                android:isScrollContainer="true"
                                android:focusable="true"/>
```

And,In Activity,

```
   InputFilter lengthFilter = new InputFilter.LengthFilter(21) {
        @Override
        public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
            if (dest.length() > getMax()) {
                Toast.makeText(Profile.this, "Screen name should not exceed more than 21 characters", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            return super.filter(source, start, end, dest, dstart, dend);
        }

        @Override
        public int getMax() {
            return super.getMax();
        }
    };

screenname.setInputFilters(new InputFilter[]{lengthFilter});
```

It does not allow to enter more than 21 characters but I am unable to intimate the user that the length must not exceed more than 21 characters because the `Toast` message inside `filter` callback is not displayed.

I have tried using `TextWatcher` but it is not getting invoked after 21st character as I have set the limit to 21 using `InputFilter`.

Anyone, Please help me find the solution.

Comment: Does getmax() return 21? If so maybe you need a >= rather than a > to make your toast come up?

Comment: Ofcourse it won't be desplayed because length can't be > then Max as you setup in xml. So this "dest.length() > getMax()" expression always be false.

Comment: If you want to allow the user to enter more than 21 characters, then you will obviously have to remove the 21character limit. You probably want a `TextWatcher` that will launch a toast/do something when the `EditText` field it is watching contains more than 21characters.

Comment: Condition  should be `if (dest.length() == getMax())` and getMax() should returns 21 .

Comment: To achive your goal you have come back to the text watcher but don't set max length. Just validate data in watcher and if text will be more then 21 chars just show the toast and remove extra character.

Comment: @ADM it shows the toast message but when I clear a character ie., when length becomes 21 to 20 , it again shows the toast. Unable to understand it.

Comment: I thing Showing toast message not good for UX . instead of it you can show a limit on right side of edit text . Like  (0/21) and change first digit with character count with a `TextWatcher`.

Comment: But our client is particular about it.:-(

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all of your responses. I have finally found the workaround with the help of ADM's Comment.

Just changed `dest.length() > getMax()` to `dest.length() == getMax()`

After the above modification, the toast was still displayed when I cleared a character using backspace.

After few analysis , I came to know that `source` returns the character the user keyed in and `dest` returns the characters being displayed in the `EditText`. As `InputFilter` is invoked before `TextWatcher`, the `dest` returns the same length when the user selecting backspace.

It is resolved by adding another validation to check if the length of the source is greater than the length of destination

```
dest.length() == getMax() && dest.toString().length() < source.toString().length()
```

Finally, the code snippet becomes

```
InputFilter lengthFilter = new InputFilter.LengthFilter(21) {
        @Override
        public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
           if (dest.length() == getMax() && dest.toString().length() < source.toString().length()) {
                Toast.makeText(Profile.this, "Screen name should not exceed more than 21 characters", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            return super.filter(source, start, end, dest, dstart, dend);
        }

        @Override
        public int getMax() {
            return super.getMax();
        }
    };
```

**Update :**
There was a strange behavior when the numbers in the dest is high **Ex:testname123456testname**. The `source` is sometimes returning only the character I have keyed-in when it has zero or lesser length of numbers in it.otherwise, it returns full characters along with the one I have just keyed-in.

`dest.toString().length() < source.toString().length()` returns `false` in the second case.

So, the code is updated as

```
 private InputFilter.LengthFilter lengthFilter = new InputFilter.LengthFilter(maxLengthOfScreenName) {
        @Override
        public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
            String numbers = dest.toString().replaceAll("[^0-9]", "");
            if (dest.toString().length() == maxLengthOfScreenName && ((dest.toString().length() < source.toString().length())
                    || (source.toString().length() == 1 && numbers.length() > 1))) {
                Toast.makeText(Profile.this,
                        "Screen name should not exceed more than " + maxLengthOfScreenName + " characters",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
            return super.filter(source, start, end, dest, dstart, dend);
        }
    };
```

Hope this will help someone else.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, also keep the max length of your edittext to 21 in xml

```
yourEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
                if(count >= 21){
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Your Alert", 
              Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {


            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: Thanks but it will show the Toast even the length is 21 . It should show only if it is greater than 21.

Comment: Just use `>` instead of `>=`... Also you should put that in `afterTextChanged` according to the docs.

Comment: Well I think if we put maxLength in xml to 21, it will never let the user enter more than 21.